# Scala - How to implement implicit JSON reader

Tags: json, scala, rest, playframework, playframework-2.2

I've implemented implicit Json Reads in order to read two fields from JSON, saleId and saleType. I wanted to make getSales method return a tuple (Int, String) representing saleId and saleType accordingly. But when I call the `getSales` method  I'm getting the following errors:

```
Error:(46, 79) No JSON deserializer found for type (Int, String). Try to implement an implicit Reader or JsonFormat for this type.
    val salesData = (salesJson \ "sales").as[(Int, String)]

Error:(46, 79) not enough arguments for method as: (implicit reader: org.json4s.Reader[(Int, String)], implicit mf: Manifest[(Int, String)])(Int, String).
Unspecified value parameters reader, mf.
    val salesData = (salesJson \ "sales").as[(Int, String)]
```

I have implemented implicit Json Reads so really confused with the first error. Here is my implementation:

```
def getsales(context: SparkContext, saleId: Int): (Int, String)= {
    val url= buildUrl(context, saleId)

    implicit val salesReader: Reads[(Int, String)] = (
      (__ \ "id_from_API").read[Int] and
        (__ \ "sale_type").read[String]
      ).tupled

    val salesJson: JValue = parse(httpStringResponse(url, context))
    val salesData = (salesJson \ "sales_stats").as[(Int, String)]

    salesData
}
```

Comment: You can read the [documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaJson) first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two notes concerning you code:

```
val salesData = (salesJson \ "sales").as[(Int, String)]
val salesData = (salesJson \ "sales_stats").as[(Int, String)]
```

might have to be the same.

Instead of JValue you might have wanted to put JsValue in the line

```
val salesJson: JValue = parse(httpStringResponse(url, context))
```

Other than that testing your JSON reader code separately from the rest of your code might be helpful.

The following worked for me:

```
import org.scalatest.WordSpec
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._
import play.api.libs.json._

class ReadsExample extends WordSpec {

  "read" in {
    val sales =
      """
          {
            "sales_stats": {
            "id_from_API": 42,
            "sale_type": "cheap"
          }
        }
        """.stripMargin

     implicit val salesReader: Reads[(Int, String)] = (
      (JsPath \ "id_from_API").read[Int] and
        (JsPath \ "sale_type").read[String]
      ).tupled

    val salesJson: JsValue = Json.parse(sales)
    val salesData = (salesJson \ "sales_stats").as[(Int, String)]
 }

}
```

Please note that the version of play-json used here is 2.3.10.

**EDIT**

code example to the question in the comment

```
import org.scalatest.WordSpec
import play.api.libs.json.Json.reads
import play.api.libs.json.{Json, _}

class ReadsExample extends WordSpec {

  "read" in {
    val sales =
      """
          {
            "id_from_API": 9,
            "sale_type": {
              "main" : "a",
              "sub" : "b"
          }
      }
    """.stripMargin

    val salesJson: JsValue = Json.parse(sales)
    val salesData = salesJson.as[Sales]
  }

}

case class Sales(id_from_API: Int, sale_type: SaleType)
case class SaleType(main: String, sub: String)

object Sales {
  implicit val st: Reads[SaleType] = reads[SaleType]
  implicit val of: Reads[Sales] = reads[Sales]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. What if I have a huge JSON file with multiple nesting levels, and don't have the "sales_stats" root element - what is the easiest way to access the fields? `val salesData = (salesJson \\ ???).as[(Int, String)]`

Comment: I would use case classes to represent the desired structure.
If the name of the case class fields correspond to the name of the json keys, you can use the reads method and write less code.